# Require() a module from a variable value

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, browserify, commonjs

This works:

```js
require('../../path/to/module')
```

This doesn't work

```js
const cfg = '../../path/to/module'
require(cfg)
```

Prints an error in Chrome Dev Tools Console (the app is packed with `browserify`):

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../../path/to/module'
```

Why does this happen and is there any way I can load a local module using a variable?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "local module"? Why is putting the path inside `require()`'s args an issue? What is the actual computation you are trying to do?

Comment: Can't you just use [dynamic import](https://v8.dev/features/dynamic-import#dynamic)?

Comment: The core thing is that, for Browserify to do its job, it needs to know what is being `require`d. If the string comes from somewhere else, it has no way to know.

Comment: The module itself exports a simple object literal that is used as a configuration object. I have multiple such configuration objects. I also have a main `cfg` in my root folder to configure my app instance and in that `cfg` object, I change the configuration object (i.e. module) that I want to use for the execution. So my require line actually is like `require(cfg.path.patterns)` and it's the `patterns` property that I update in my base config. Hope that makes sense..!

Comment: @loganfsmyth - so you're saying this is a browserify specific issue?

Comment: What would you expect to be in the Browserify bundled output? All possible files that could be in the `patterns` property? How do you toggle the values of `cfg.path.patterns`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I understand now, thanks. Browserify is cycling through all of the dependencies as part of the build, and it can't determine a dependency from a variable string as it won't know all possible values of that string. Makes sense now - thanks!

Comment: this is still relevant and i can't find reasoning for this anywhere